# Custom plotter for only specific series

Tags: dygraphs

I have a graph with two series. I'd like to plot one using the default plotter and one using a custom plotter. Is that possible?

I see there is the option  `plotter: function(e) { }` which is called for each series.
However, I'd like the first series to be plotted using the default plotter.
Is that possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the plotter on a per-series basis. For example, if your columns are X, Y1 and Y2:

```
new Dygraph(div, data, {
  series: {
    // no per-series plotter for Y1
    'Y2': {
      plotter: function(e) { ... }
    }
  }
});
```

The "Bar & Line Chart" on the [plotters demo](http://dygraphs.com/tests/plotters.html) shows a complete example of this.